# Why does it say no space available when a lot are avaliable?

Tags: linux, rsync, df

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        30G  290M   28G   2% /
devtmpfs         63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs            63G     0   63G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            63G   43M   63G   1% /run
tmpfs            63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2        30G   13G   15G  47% /usr
/dev/sda5        30G  2.2G   26G   8% /tmp
/dev/sda7       148G   61M  141G   1% /data0
/dev/sda6        30G  671M   28G   3% /var
tmpfs            13G     0   13G   0% /run/user/60422
/dev/sdb1       274G   65M  260G   1% /data1
/dev/sdc1       439G   73M  417G   1% /data2
/dev/sdd1       439G   73M  417G   1% /data3
/dev/sde1       439G   73M  417G   1% /data4
/dev/sdf1       439G   73M  417G   1% /data5
/dev/sdg1       439G   73M  417G   1% /data6
/dev/sdh1       439G   73M  417G   1% /data7
/dev/sdi1       439G   73M  417G   1% /data8
/dev/sdj1       439G   73M  417G   1% /data9
/dev/sdk1       439G   73M  417G   1% /data10
/dev/sdl1       439G   73M  417G   1% /data11
```

I am in my own directory:

```
/usr/home/cong/data
```

And in this directory, I am executing a rsync command to copy a 24G file from a remote machine to my home directory on this machine. On the half way of copying, it reports:

```
rsync: write failed on "/usr/home/cong/data/content_8_days.txt": No space left on device (28)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(393) [receiver=3.1.2]
```

Is that because my directory is under /usr, which only has 15G avaiable? In such a case, how to make use of other spaces under, i.e. /data1, /data2?

Comment: Looking at that `df` output, your system sure looks like it could use some LVM or even ZFS...

Comment: You can mount, give yourself ownership & permissions to your other partitions and link them back into /home. I link all of them to my data partition, but some just link media or photos as they may be large. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk You will have to use a separate mount for each data partition and link its folders separately.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that because my directory is under /usr, which only has 15G avaiable?

yes

> In such a case, how to make use of other spaces under, i.e. /data1, /data2?

Copy the file to one of them.

e.g:

> /dev/sda2        30G   13G   15G  47% /usr